# mysql/c++ program not compiling (problem with boost)

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, linker

*c:\program files\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.0\include\cppconn\connection.h(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/variant.hpp': No such file or directory*

What do I need to do to solve this problem? This is a simple hello world program that i copied from here. http://blog.ulf-wendel.de/?p=215#hello I have downloaded boost and have added the boost file path to  visual studios "additional include directories" under c/c++ but I'm not sure I'm doing it right as the tutorial doesn't seem to have instructions for boost for whatever reason.

Comment: Sounds like you added the wrong path. The boost distribution consists of a toplevel folder e.g. boost-1.46 and then subfolders boost, libs, etc. under that. You need to specify the top-level folder (e.g. boost-1.46) in your include path.

Comment: Ah I definitely went to the \lib folder

Comment: @HighCommander4 : Repost that as an answer please.